# Confused about creating a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I found a question on stackoverflow that was asked over a year ago that is similar to my database structure in mysql. The questions is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943749/mysql-implementing-tables-into-database)

The answer that has been provided makes sense except the following table:

```
Message_type: message_type_id, description (1:public, 2:friends, 3:specific_recipients)
```

Can someone help me figure out how to create the table that implements the `(1:public, 2:friends, 3:specific_recipients)` property please?

EDIT

```
User: user_id, given_name, ...

Message: message_id, owner_id (fk User), subject, body, posted, message_type_id (fk Message_type)...

Message_recipients: user_id (fk User), message_id (fk Message)

Message_type: message_type_id, description (1:public, 2:friends, 3:specific_recipients)
```

So I tried implementing my database based on this but I am having problem setting it up. 
First problem: the `message` table has a `FK` called `message_type_id` but if you look at the previous OP's question, that field is called `isPublic` and that is not a `PK`. How do I change the `isPublic` field to a `FK` without deleting its records. Also do I need to specify any `UPDATES` or `ALTER` conditions while creating those tables.

Comment: Question about a question is meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like `Message_type` has the two columns `message_type_id` and `description` and contains 3 rows containing the values in brackets, like this:

```
message_type_id | description
----------------+--------------------
1               | public
2               | friends
3               | specific_recipients
```

There are a few ways to write SQL to do this, one way (with `message_type_id` as primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE Message_type (message_type_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                           description VARCHAR(100))
SELECT 1 AS message_type_id, 'public' AS description
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'friends'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'specific_recipients'
```

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) for more.

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE Message_type (message_type_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                           description VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO message_type
VALUES (1, 'public'), (2, 'friends'), (3, 'specific_recipients')
```

**EDIT for question EDIT:**

If you have already created the `Message` table with (for example):

```
CREATE TABLE Message (
  message_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  isPublic tinyint(4) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
);
```

This would replace (a presumably boolean) `isPublic` with `message_type_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE Message
ADD COLUMN message_type_id INT REFERENCES Message_type(message_type_id);

# classified everything that's not public as friends
UPDATE Message
SET message_type_id = CASE WHEN isPublic = 1 THEN 1
                           ELSE 2
                      END;

ALTER TABLE Message DROP COLUMN isPublic;
```

Comment: It's just 3 `INSERT` statements (or one statement with 3 VALUES lists). What's the problem?

Comment: @corybaxter, `create table message_type (message_type_id integer primary key, description text)` - something like that, you can find syntax for `create table` command in MySQL documentation

Comment: @SpongeBobFan I know it was text but was making sure if it meant something else because of the way it was written

Comment: @corybaxter, then to fill the table `insert into message_type (message_type_id, description) values (1, public), (2, friends), (3, specific_recipients);`. Check MySQL documentation for the right syntax if it don't work

Comment: also would int(10) be allright to use for values upto 1,000,000,000 records?

Comment: @corybaxter Yes, that would be big enough. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: Hi all, I tried implementing this and had a question. Cant I just include an `INT` field into `Message_recipients: user_id (fk User), message_id (fk Message), messageType`. would that work fine too? that way i dont have to create an extra table

Comment: @corybaxter I would not suggest it - you won't be able to limit the allowed values, and just numbers here won't really mean much - you'll have to consult external documentation to find out what `messageType = 1` means.

Comment: @Dukeling Hi, sorry to bother you again but if you have any spare time, can you please look at my edit to the question please.